# What am I doing wrong with my questions?

Tags: discussion

My past few questions on SO, all pertaining to the same thing, are getting downvoted and I'm not sure why.  I thought my questions were easily written and understandable, limited code but enough to explain the issue, researched, and asked in a satisfying way.  I don't expect an answer, only suggestion on where to step to now.

Why can't downvotes come with a required explanation rather than simply downvoting and moving on?  I just want to improve my posts to help me and future users to the site and if something is missing in my post, I would rather know about it instead of worrying and wondering what exactly I missed or if I asked it in a wrong manner.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. The questions seem reasonable enough. Were they edited at all (the downvotes coming from a previous, worse, revision)?

Comment: Not that I recall.  I guess I learned something new today as well, with duplicate threads equaling downvotes :), I guess I will just never understand this site. You can give me all the duplicate threads you want but that doesn't really help me in pertaining to my own posts, as if I was missing something from them to be giving me down votes.  These duplicate threads are great to read and help give me some insight but from what I read, if it's missing one part of the readers personal opinion, it gets 'downvoted and moved on', no logical reason or explanation.

Comment: @Criel meta can be a pretty harsh place. After reading up in the [help center](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help), I might suggest hopping into a chat room and talking to people there. I'd suggest [tavern on the meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta) since there are a lot of friendly people in there as well as quite a few mod regulars.

Comment: It's also important to remember that voting on Meta doesn't impact your reputation, so people seem to throw downvotes around more casually here. It's nothing to worry too much about, if there's nothing fundamentally wrong with your post.

Comment: Also to the downvoters: is this really the kind of user you want to reprimand? The guy/girl reaching out for help on meta about their content? Sure, it can probably be closed as dupe. But, punishing users who reach out and want to learn how to more positively contribute is kind of insane.

Comment: @Criel Duplicates don't *generally* lead to downvotes. One issue with your question here is that you suggest a comment for downvotes, a suggestion repeatedly made by folks who did not think it through. The regulars on Meta are tired of seeing it. (However, as I can't read the mind of the downvoters, I cannot be certain that *this* is the reason your question here is being downvoted.) Also, if you want this question to be about improving your other questions, then make this the focus of your question here. The suggestion about comments is a distraction from this goal.

Comment: Explaining downvotes takes effort that could be spend on answering good questions.  How many of your downvotes have you explained, (I'm guessing none)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anything, your questions may be a bit verbose - it's good to go into detail if you've got a very complicated problem, but if you're describing a fairly simple target behavior, it's helpful to try to boil down what you're saying to be as succinct as possible so as to not bog down the reader - you keep sort of looping back in your explanation, and repeating things like "What is the reason for this?" -- the fact that you want to know the answer to your question and that it's making it hard to work on your project is implied by you asking it, so you don't need to spend to much time reiterating it.

That said, I don't think they're so bad I would have downvoted them. Just a hint on how to improve them in the future.

As to the second point, that of enforcing a mandatory comment with downvotes: there's been extensive discussion on why this isn't done already. The posts linked in the comments should catch you up on what's been debated and explained there in the past.